# Automatically fill in fields that depend on contents of FileField when creating an object from a ModelForm

Tags: python, django

Supposing I have a model representing a photo. It contains an image file, a description of the photo, and the EXIF data contained within the image file:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    photo_file = models.FileField()
    photo_description = models.TextField()
    photo_exif = models.TextField()
```

And then I have a form that the user uses to upload a photo. It requires an image file, and the description of the photo.

```
class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('photo_file', 'photo_description')
```

It doesn't make sense to ask the user for `photo_exif` within the form, because it's something the server should automatically fill in when it receives the image file.

Thus, when creating a `Photo` object from the form, I cannot simply use `photo_object = form.save()` since `photo_exif` is a required field. Instead, I have to set `photo_exif` before saving the object created from the form:

```
photo_object = form.save(commit=False)
photo_object.photo_exif = "..."
photo_object.save()
```

But doing it manually like this every time is a buggy process.

Is there a way to make the form itself (or the perhaps the object itself) automatically fill in the `photo_exif` field from the photo file every time, so that I can just use `photo_object = form.save()`?

Comment: You should take a look at post_save() or pre_save() signal receiver. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-save

Comment: You can add a clean() method to the form that extracts and sets the exit data to cleaned_data

Comment: I've already tried overriding the `clean()` method in `PhotoForm` and then setting `self.cleaned_data['photo_exif'] = "..."`, but it didn't do anything.